# Not sure if this question is on topic

Tags: discussion

I wanted to ask a question, not specifically about a problem I'm having, but about the generational change in dating patterns.  Specifically, **at what point does a dating couple assume that they are dating exclusively?**  I expect that the answer is going to vary widely between age-bands, specifically that the younger cohort will expect a definite conversation about it.

Okay, all that said... I'm not sure such a question really fits the format of IPSE and wanted to get some insight on that before inflicting my amateur sociology projects on the main site.

Comment: that seems too broad, unless you specify a specific culture audience

Comment: Maybe [Cognitive Sciences SE](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/)? Seems more like a behavioral topic possibly answerable with a study rather than personal experience.